# "zwei Jahre" / "für zwei Jahre" / "zwei Jahre lang"

Tags: usage, time

> (a) Ich wohnte zwei Jahre in Berlin.
>
> (b) Ich wohnte für zwei Jahre in Berlin.
>
> (c) Ich wohnte zwei Jahre lang in Berlin.

Sind alle Sätze grammatisch? Gibt es Unterschiede mit der Bedeutung?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja alle Sätze sind grammatikalisch richtig. Es gibt keinen Unterschied in der Bedeutung, höchstens, dass das erste Beispiel eher im Sprachgebrauch vorkommt.
Zur Fragenformulierung:
1. "Sind alle Sätze grammatisch/grammatikalisch korrekt?" (Nur als Alternative)
2. "Gibt es Unterschiede ***in*** der Bedeutung?"

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung nach kommt sogar noch eher das hier gar nicht vorgestellte Perfekt in der Umgangssprache zur Anwendung: »Ich habe zwei Jahre (lang) in Berlin gewohnt«. Präteritum ist in der Umgangssprache vor allem mündlich eher selten zu finden.

Comment: "Ich wohnte für zwei Jahre in Berlin" ist für mich kein Deutsch. Hier übersetzt jemand for two years (wie lange) Wort für Wort ins Deutsche.

Comment: @rogermue, das sehe ich nicht so. Für mich ist das ein ganz normaler Satz. Er hat IMHO aber eine leichte Tendenz zu bedeuten: *für zwei Jahre war ich in  Berlin*, jetzt geht es wieder nach Hause!

Comment: Ich stimme @rogermue zu – für mich ist die Präposition *für* nur für zukünftige Zeitspannen. Das passt auch gut zu [den im Duden aufgelisteten Bedeutungen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/f%C3%BCr) II.3.a und II.3.b.

Answer (score 2):

Alle Sätze sind grammatikalisch richtig. Einheimische würden jedoch eher sagen:
"Ich habe zwei Jahre lang in Berlin gewohnt". Das hat keine andere Bedeutung als die von dir genannten Sätze (außer dass es eine andere Zeit ist grammatikalisch gesehen), aber so würde man es eben in Deutschland sagen.

Answer (score -2):

Es heißt richtig: Ich wohne seit 2 Jahren in Berlin / Seit 2 Jahren wohne ich in Berlin.

Comment: Nein, das hat eine ganz andere Bedeutung als "Ich wohnte zwei Jahre in Berlin."